# Array int for query db

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, ado.net

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id from table", conn);
MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

for example i get 4 row, so 23,3,12,9

how i can get array this integer?

```
int[] arr = { 23, 3, 12, 9 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
IEnumerable<int> r;
using (reader)
{
    r = Read(reader);
}
int[] arr = r.ToArray();
```

where you can implement the method in various ways:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Read(IDataReader reader)
{
    IList<int> list = new List<int>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        list.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
    }
    return list;
}
```

or (extending Aghilas's answer):

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Read(IDataReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return reader.GetInt32(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use yield iterator

```
while(reader.Read()
{
    yield return reader.GetInt32(0);
}
```